# With static IP on Hyper V ping from Host fails

Tags: hyper-v, static-ip-address

I have configured a VM on Hyprev. With DHCP the ping works fine but when ever i tried to set  it to static IP ping from host to Vm always returns time out .I am using Externalswitch for sharing the connection .Below the snapshot of Externalswitch. 
[image]

Any help on this will be helpful.

Comment: have you tried disabling the firewall and ping? my guess is that the network profile changes when you set the static ip and thus the firewall blocks icmp packets

Comment: Yes tried even added the port which needed to be forwarded .If its firewall isuue then how can it work with DHCP IP